# emacs24のanything-show-completionの使い方について

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs24にanythingをelpaで一括で入れてinit.elに下の内容を記述したのですが、
anything-show-completionはどのタイミングで起動し使うのでしょうか？
補完候補がでてきません。

```
(when (require 'anything nil t)
  (when (require 'anything-complete nil t)
    ;; lispシンボルの補完候補の再検索時間
    (anything-lisp-complete-symbol-set-timer 150))
  (require 'anything-show-completion nil t))
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問そのものの回答ではありませんが、`anything`は`helm`に移行されてるので、特に理由がなければ`helm`を利用されたほうが良いと思います。 https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm

Comment: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/rubikitch/20090419/1240072841 を見ると anything-complete.el 、 anything-rcodetools.el 、 anything-dabbrev-expand.el 、 perl-completion.elのみ対応しているとなっています. 何でもかんでも anythingインタフェースを使いたい場合は (anything-completion-mode +1)とするとよいようです. PS. 特に問題等なければ @ironsandさんのおっしゃるとおり helmを使った方が良いと思います. helmで同様のことをやる場合は (helm-mode +1)となります.